Rules to chant the given Saraswati mantra
Saraswati namastyubhyam varade kaam rupini
What are the methods to chant this Saraswati mantra and how many times should anyone chant it get any results ?

what do you mean by 'results'?

Blessings of the deity in studies and related fields .@SwamiVishwananda
